# Pre-named D3DCOLOR header files anywhere?

Tags: colors, direct3d

In GDI+ you can do

Color::Green,
Color::AliceBlue, etc, as listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534427%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I'm looking for a similar pre-baked color enumeration for D3DCOLOR structs from a DirectX header, but I don't know where one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out if you just `#include <gdiplus.h>`, the Color class defined therein is completely compatible with D3DCOLOR.  So you can use the Color:: constants in GDIPlus when drawing with D3D.